# Fullcalendar jQuery prev and next buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using Fullcalendar and when I click on the prev or next buttons, on the header, I want to get the month. How can I do that?

Comment: See my example in [jQuery get the next month data using fullcalendar plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278295/jquery-get-the-next-month-data-using-fullcalendar-plugin/19135058#19135058)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `events` like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: '/myfeed.php'
});
```

And when the user click the previous or next button, it will call the myfeed.php automatically, like this: `?start=1262332800&end=1265011200&_=1263178646`.

You will be able to catch this in server side and it's Unix Time Format.